# My system keeps locking me into safe mode and boots directly to root shell

Tags: raspbian, networking, boot, root

Help! I keep getting boot error on my RPi and being locked into safe mode only having access to root shell and losing network connectivity!

It is the forth time this happens, the first time I have made multiple update, upgrade, dist-upgrade and rpi-update; then it happened after I used dist-upgrade, and now I have kept track of everything I installed and it was, in this order:

After first run I updated&upgraded,

Then I installed vsftpd, apache2, deluge, samba, finger, whois, weavedconnectd, ddclient and curlftpfs

and now it locked me again after reboot!

After I get locked, none of the systemctl default commands I'm suggested to run by the Raspbian system work and the only way I find to get the system back to normal is reinstalling the whole thing again! It's terrible!

I have ran journalctl -xb and dmesg and these were the results:

[dmesg report](http://www.joaodavid.net/misc/boot_report)

[journalctl -xb report](http://www.joaodavid.net/misc/journalctl-xb.report)

please, Im going to reinstall the whole thing...again...but if someone can provide a solution for this or at least a way to bypass it without reinstalling the whole system I would be VERY appreciated!!

Thanks to all in advance

Comment: If you are going to post output include in your question - NOT link to external sites. Next time DO NOT run `rpi-update` "In normal circumstances there is NEVER a need to run rpi-update as it always gets you to the leading edge firmware and kernel and because that may be a testing version it could leave your RPi unbootable". https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=916911#p916911 PS check your storage - your issue may just be insufficient space.